# How to index through logical vectors properly in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, logical-operators

I have this piece of code

```
1  all_baseline_data(:,24)=(all_baseline_data(:,19)-all_baseline_data(:,16));
2  all_baseline_data(:,24)=judgment_error_b
3  for i_b=1:numel(all_baseline_data,1)
4    if all_baseline_data(i_b,24)<-1280
5       correction_b(i_b,25)=all_baseline_data(i_b,24)+2560;
6    end
7  end
8  all_baseline_data(:,25)=judgment_error_b(correction_b);
```

1. when I run it, it computes the subtraction and creates a new vector (lines 1&2) but it doesn't perform the if statement
2. I'm also struggling to attach the newly-created 'correction_b' vector to the main all_baseline_data array (line 8)

Comment: Besides your issue, use `elseif` instead of `else if`. It will save you nested `end`s and make the code more readable.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @mvai done - please ignore the 'elseif'; if it works with 'if', it'll work with 'elseif' as well

Comment: @excaza done - please see above

Comment: Not done, that does not function on its own.